# How to resolve a citation compilation error which occurs randomly

Tags: bibtex, citing, compiling, compilation-error

Occasionally when I compile a multi-chapter document it refuses to compile and says that there are math equations in the citations.

If I comment out all lines with citations in one particular chapter, and then compile, the document renders. Then if I un-comment out all of those lines, it compiles and renders.

I would believe that there is some incorrect notation buried in the .bib file, but I went through and used the code below to resolve all of the errors I could find in the bibliography.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{temp.bib}
\end{document}
```

I have tried to compile from scratch, and that does not resolve the issue. This error is also only occurring with the citations from one chapter. I uncommented slowly to try to identify a particular citation causing the error, but again it works essentially only after everything in the one chapter has been commented out and then uncommented.

The line that is throwing the error looks like this, but it shows up for about 5 paragraphs of citations in the document.

`particularly respiratory illness\cite{krishnamoorthy_prevalence_2021, munywoki_source_2014, scott_risk_2019}`

[image: This shows up in the bibtex file occasionally, and I've just been deleting the red dots, but I can't copy them, so I cant search for them and don't know what they're called.]
[image: Picture of the error message]

```
@article{krishnamoorthy_prevalence_2021,
    title        = {Prevalence and risk factors associated with latent tuberculosis infection among household contacts of smear positive pulmonary tuberculosis patients in {South} {India}},
    author       = {Krishnamoorthy, Yuvaraj and Ezhumalai, Komala and Murali, Sharan and Rajaa, Sathish and Jose, Maria and Sathishkumar, Abilasha and Soundappan, Govindarajan and Horsburgh, Charles and Hochberg, Natasha and Johnson, William Evan and Knudsen, Selby and Salgame, Padmini and Ellner, Jerrold and Prakash Babu, Senbagavalli and Sarkar, Sonali},
    year         = 2021,
    journal      = {Tropical Medicine \& International Health},
    volume       = 26,
    number       = 12,
    pages        = {1645--1651},
    doi          = {10.1111/tmi.13693},
    issn         = {1365-3156},
    url          = {https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/tmi.13693},
    urldate      = {2023-07-01},
    copyright    = {2021 John Wiley \& Sons Ltd},
    note         = {\_eprint: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/tmi.13693},
    abstract     = {Objective We aimed to determine the prevalence and find the risk factors associated with latent tuberculosis infection (LTBI) among the household contacts (HHC) of pulmonary TB patients. Methods This cohort study was conducted from 2014 to 2019. Pretested standardised questionnaires and tools were used for data collection. The prevalence of LTBI among HHCs of TB patients was summarised as proportion with 95\% confidence interval (CI). Mixed-effects generalised linear modelling function (meglm) in STATA with family Poisson and log link was performed to find the factors associated with LTBI. Results In total, 1523 HHC of pulmonary TB patients were included in the study. Almost all HHC shared their residence with the index case (IC) for more than a year; 25\% shared the same bed with the IC. The prevalence of LTBI among the HHC of TB patients was 52.6\% (95\% CI: 50.1–55.1\%). In an adjusted model, we found that among HHC belonging to the age group of 19–64 years (aIRR = 1.2; 95\% CI: 1.1–1.3; p-value: 0.02), to the age group 65 years (aIRR = 1.4, 95\% CI: 1.1–1.9, p-value: 0.02) and sharing the same bed with the IC (aIRR = 1.2, 95\% CI: 1.1–1.3, p value: 0.04) were independent determinants of LTBI among the HHC. Conclusion One in two household contacts of TB patients have latent tuberculosis infection. This underscores the need of targeted contact screening strategies, effective contact tracing and testing using standardised methods in high TB burden settings.},
    language     = {en},
    keywords     = {alcohol consumption, latent TB infection, pulmonary tuberculosis, TST}
}
@article{munywoki_source_2014,
    title        = {The {Source} of {Respiratory} {Syncytial} {Virus} {Infection} {In} {Infants}: {A} {Household} {Cohort} {Study} {In} {Rural} {Kenya}},
    shorttitle   = {The {Source} of {Respiratory} {Syncytial} {Virus} {Infection} {In} {Infants}},
    author       = {Munywoki, Patrick K. and Koech, Dorothy C. and Agoti, Charles N. and Lewa, Clement and Cane, Patricia A. and Medley, Graham F. and Nokes, D. J.},
    year         = 2014,
    month        = jun,
    journal      = {J Infect Dis},
    volume       = 209,
    number       = 11,
    pages        = {1685--1692},
    doi          = {10.1093/infdis/jit828},
    issn         = {0022-1899},
    url          = {https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4017365/},
    urldate      = {2023-07-01},
    abstract     = {Background. Respiratory syncytial virus (RSV) vaccine development for direct protection of young infants faces substantial obstacles. Assessing the potential of indirect protection using different strategies, such as targeting older children or mothers, requires knowledge of the source of infection to the infants., Methods. We undertook a prospective study in rural Kenya. Households with a child born after the preceding RSV epidemic and 1 elder sibling were recruited. Nasopharyngeal swab samples were collected every 3–4 days irrespective of symptoms from all household members throughout the RSV season of 2009–2010 and tested for RSV using molecular techniques., Results. From 451 participants in 44 households a total of 15 396 nasopharyngeal swab samples were samples were collected, representing 86\% of planned sampling. RSV was detected in 37 households (84\%) and 173 participants (38\%) and 28 study infants (64\%). The infants acquired infection from within (15 infants; 54\%) or outside (9 infants; 32\%) the household; in 4 households the source of infant infection was inconclusive. Older children were index case patients for 11 (73\%) of the within-household infant infections, and 10 of these 11 children were attending school., Conclusion. We demonstrate that school-going siblings frequently introduce RSV into households, leading to infection in infants.},
    pmid         = 24367040,
    pmcid        = {PMC4017365}
}
@article{scott_risk_2019,
    title        = {Risk factors and patterns of household clusters of respiratory viruses in rural {Nepal}},
    author       = {Scott, E. M. and Magaret, A. and Kuypers, J. and Tielsch, J. M. and Katz, J. and Khatry, S. K. and Stewart, L. and Shrestha, L. and LeClerq, S. C. and Englund, J. A. and Chu, H. Y.},
    year         = 2019,
    month        = oct,
    journal      = {Epidemiol Infect},
    volume       = 147,
    pages        = {e288},
    doi          = {10.1017/S0950268819001754},
    issn         = {0950-2688},
    url          = {https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6805793/},
    urldate      = {2023-07-01},
    abstract     = {Viral pneumonia is an important cause of death and morbidity among infants worldwide. Transmission of non-influenza respiratory viruses in households can inform preventative interventions and has not been well-characterised in South Asia. From April 2011 to April 2012, household members of pregnant women enrolled in a randomised trial of influenza vaccine in rural Nepal were surveyed weekly for respiratory illness until 180 days after birth. Nasal swabs were tested by polymerase chain reaction for respiratory viruses in symptomatic individuals. A transmission event was defined as a secondary case of the same virus within 14 days of initial infection within a household. From 555 households, 825 initial viral illness episodes occurred, resulting in 79 transmission events. The overall incidence of transmission was 1.14 events per 100 person-weeks. Risk of transmission incidence was associated with an index case age 1–4 years (incidence rate ratio (IRR) 2.35; 95\% confidence interval (CI) 1.40–3.96), coinfection as initial infection (IRR 1.94; 95\% CI 1.05–3.61) and no electricity in household (IRR 2.70; 95\% CI 1.41–5.00). Preventive interventions targeting preschool-age children in households in resource-limited settings may decrease the risk of transmission to vulnerable household members, such as young infants.},
    pmid         = 31607271,
    pmcid        = {PMC6805793}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: latex never acts randomly. It follows the code in the document.  If you do not show the code with the error, and don't even show the error message, it will be hard to help

Comment: I have edited it to add a picture and some code snippets. The reason I say randomly is that it seems to be occuring only occasionally, and as I've described, I've found a workaround, but I would prefer to actually solve the issue rather than commenting the things in and out to get it to render. That's the part that feels non-deterministic.

Comment: "math equations" in the citation means probably that you have an underscore or something similar in the bib.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too, I've gone through and tried to find all symbols which might throw an error, but I could definitely have missed some. The fact that it's happening inconsistently is quite strange to me.

Comment: @Tessa have you tried deleting all of your `aux` files and then compiling it from scratch? It sounds like there is an issue with the aux file (or some other file) which doesn't exist when you remove that problematic citation, so when you run it the next time it has a working aux file to work from. Without more information it is impossible to help though, could you make a small example of code that makes your error and put it in your question please?

Comment: I will work on it, my suspicion is that if I can do that I'll be able to isolate the citation that is causing the error. The minimal example I just tried with the citation in my post has no issue in a smaller document.

I am just deleting the aux files by clearing the cache. It doesn't seem to be making a difference, but that does seem like a very reasonable explanation.

Comment: show the bib entries for `krishnamoorthy_prevalence_2021, munywoki_source_2014, scott_risk_2019}`

Comment: Added, but in my small document where I have the original code I have a test line which runs that citation and it doesn't throw an error there. 

I kind of think there might be missing brackets somewhere in the .bib file which is causing this. Though I have been finding special characters which I have been removing.

Comment: I think there's some complication with one of the packages I'm using. Or I've still missed some special characters. I have deleted all of the abstracts, and tried to find all of the special characters. The citations work with no errors in the simple file. I deleted all the parenthesis in case there was something unmatched. There are even numbers of curly braces.

Comment: Comment half the chapter. Then a quarter etc. to narrow it down.

Comment: It really does seem to be non-deterministic. (I know it's not, but the behavior is funky) I have the whole chapter copied into another file, and it runs perfectly well. But as the multi chapter document..
There are 6 paragraphs causing the error. Put them into the chapter with nothing else. Slowly comment each one out. Find that it's probably the last paragraph of that segment. Split it up by the citations. Comment the first section of that last paragraph out, compiles! Uncomment section, clear cache, refresh, compiles. Repeat doesnt compile. Comment out other section, compiles.

Comment: Such seemingly random errors can happen if packages write parts of the document in auxiliary files, and if there is an issue with this. Some packages spilt contents at special characters or combinations of special characters. If these are inside a math environment, errors of the type you get can arise because a math environment no longer gets closed. I am not saying that this is what happening here but if everything else fails this may be something to look into.